# Ubuntu 22 Apps UI Flickering when start

Tags: 22.04, xorg, screen, wayland, slack

[image]

In Ubuntu 22.04 app screens flicker like the following images (Slack) when it launches. I found a few apps(Slack, Brave Browser) that have the same problem.

```
echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE
x11
```

Kernel version

```
uname -r
6.5.0-25-generic
```

Does anyone have a similar experience, how did you fix it

Comment: Do you have a dedicated graphics card (e.g. NVidia)? Then open Software & Sources, go to the additional drivers tab, choose a different driver, and reboot

Comment: Ordinary Laptop. Lenovo-IdeaPad-S340.  AMD® Radeon vega 3 graphics
Additional drivers tab is empty @Archisman Panigrahi

Comment: Did you install Slack/Brave through debian packages or snap?

Comment: I guess snap –––– sudo snap install brave @ArchismanPanigrahi

Comment: Can you try installing the deb from its website and uninstall the snap?

Comment: Got it. The problem comes from snap @ArchismanPanigrahi

Answer (score 1):

It happened because of the snap. After removing the snap and installing the deb. The Brave browser as well as Slack works fine.